# How to Isolate some part of HTML code style & formatting?

Tags: html, css, formatting, embed, isolation

I've some part of HTML code which is generated by TinyMCE and I have to embed is within another HTML page, but when I do this, sometimes it formatting affects by container page & some other times it affects container page.
I need something like a sandbox to put my TinyMCE generated HTML code inside is and completely isolates my HTML code snippet from parent page, somehow that they don't affect each other at all (I don't want to use frames).

```
<html><!-- container page -->
     ...
     <div id="sandBox"><!--TinyMCE generated HTML goes here--></div>
     ...
</html>
```

Comment: I know it's a crappy solution, but have you tried using an iframe?

Comment: Basically, *you can't*...you can *override* styling by starting every rule with `#sandbox` but that's about it.